# Directory contents comparer by file content, ignoring name

Tags: comparison, file-comparison, file-compare

Is there an utility to compare the contents of a directory by file contents alone?

I have two sets of files, most of them binary same, but some of them different; but each files of a pair have different names even if their contents match.

Is there a tool that is able to compare the directory contents based on the actual file contents and does not require the filename to match?

I'm on Windows, but also interested in GNU/Linux tools.

Comment: don't know but one method could be to order them such that they pair up so the first in dir1 is to be compared with the first in dir2. then rename each file to its position. so dir1 will have files called first, second, third, fourth e.t.c.  similarly dir2. Then they'll have the same names. and you'll know which files are meant in your comparison.

Comment: Will one of the many duplicate file finders not suffice?

Answer (score 0):

This may work, I had some trouble with it, but I've dumped enough time into it that it's worth sharing in case it helps someone else.

Some caveats: `Get-FileHash` requires Powershell 4. This isn't doing anything with recursion.

```
$left = dir .\leftDir\* | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5
$right = dir .\rightDir\* | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5
$leftOnly = compare -passthru ($left | select hash) ($right | select hash)
$rightOnly = compare -passthru ($right | select hash) ($left | select hash)

echo "Print left only files"
foreach ($l in $leftOnly)
{
    foreach ($file in $left)
    {
        if ($file.Hash -eq $l.Hash) { echo $file.Path }
    }
}

echo ""

echo "Print right only files"
foreach ($r in $rightOnly)
{
    foreach ($file in $right)
    {
        if ($file.Hash -eq $r.Hash) { echo $file.Path }
    }
}
```